# How do I add a formula next to a copied data range with Google Apps Script?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have trouble understanding arrays, but I know it's what I need to do to fix my problem. Presently, I'm copying data I need from another sheet onto a tab, copying that data table, then pasting it into another tab on that sheet. I now need to add another column to the end of this finally produced data that is a formula in each cell adjacent, which is column AP starting in AP2. Here is the script:

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('some id');
  var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Outcome'); // ss = source sheet
  var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('other id');
  var target = destination.getSheetByName('Final');

  ss.copyTo(destination);

  var data = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Outcome');
  var infoTable = data.getRange(2, 1, data.getLastRow(), data.getLastColumn());
  var lastRow = target.getLastRow();

  infoTable.copyTo(target.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});

  destination.setActiveSheet(destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Outcome'));
  destination.deleteActiveSheet();
}
```

The formula I want to append each copied row with is the following:

```
'=vlookup($I2, IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/<yet another id>/edit#gid=1203869430", "Source_Hours!A:B"), 2, false)'
```

Here's how I tried to do it:

```
 function CopyDataToNewFile() {
      var sss = SpreadsheetApp.openById('some id');
      var ss = sss.getSheetByName('Outcome'); // ss = source sheet
      var destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('other id');
      var target = destination.getSheetByName('Final');


  ss.copyTo(destination);

  var data = destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Outcome');
  var infoTable = data.getRange(2, 1, data.getLastRow(), data.getLastColumn());
  var lastRow = target.getLastRow();

  infoTable.copyTo(target.getRange(lastRow + 1, 1), {contentsOnly: true});


 target.getRange(2,infoTable.getLastColumn()+1,infoTable.getLastRow(),1).setFormula('=vlookup($I2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f7_unFqRkI6O2EHBLsNGLRCH5j9rlEXBdVnRLTgS_lM/edit#gid=1203869430","Source_Hours!A:B"),2,false)');


  destination.setActiveSheet(destination.getSheetByName('Copy of Outcome'));
  destination.deleteActiveSheet();
}
```

It works the first time I run the script, but the next time I run it, it does not add the formula in the last column. I am not a programmer, just know enough to be dangerous. :)

Comment: How do you think you should approach this? Conceptually, everything you need is already in your script. You need 1) the first row you copy your table to; 2) the number of rows you copy; and 3) the number of columns you copy. All that's left is to select the range defined by `(<first row written to>, <column after table column>, <number of table rows>, <number of columns of data to write>)` and then set the formula of that range

Comment: @tehhowch Thanks for the tip, I got a little further but I can't seem to conceptualize how to get it to work after the first iteration. Here's what I added: 
 
 `target.getRange(2,infoTable.getLastColumn()+1,infoTable.getLastRow(),1).setFormula('=vlookup($I2,IMPORTRANGE("https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1f7_unFqRkI6O2EHBLsNGLRCH5j9rlEXBdVnRLTgS_lM/edit#gid=1203869430","Source_Hours!A:B"),2,false)');
   `

Comment: Sorry, I was using unclear language. By "iteration" I just meant the first time I ran the script.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your solution was close. My recommended approach is to create a reference to the first row your script will copy into -- `target.getLastRow() + 1` -- and then use this reference for both the datatable copy, and the formula write. Your script also had a possible issue in that you assumed that the sheet name was always `"Copy of Outcome"` -- this is not strictly guaranteed to be true (consider copying a sheet twice without deleting the first copy). Instead, bind the return value of [`Sheet#copyTo`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/sheet#copytospreadsheet), since it is the newly created worksheet copy. In this manner, the name of the copied sheet is irrelevant - the script doesn't need it to function as intended.

```
function CopyDataToNewFile() {
  const source = SpreadsheetApp.openById('some id').getSheetByName('Outcome');
  const destination = SpreadsheetApp.openById('other id');
  const target = destination.getSheetByName('Final');
  if (!source || !target)
    throw new Error("Missing required worksheets (sheet names not found)");

  // Copy the source sheet and get a reference to the copy.
  var datasheet = source.copyTo(destination);
  var infoTable = datasheet.getRange(2, 1, datasheet.getLastRow(), datasheet.getLastColumn());

  // Copy the table contents to the end of the target sheet.
  // Determine the first row we are writing data into.
  const startRow = target.getLastRow() + 1;
  infoTable.copyTo(target.getRange(startRow, 1), {contentsOnly: true});
  // Set a column formula in the adjacent column.
  target.getRange(startRow, 1 + infoTable.getNumColumns(), infoTable.getNumRows(), 1)
    .setFormula("some formula");

  // Remove the intermediate sheet.
  destination.deleteSheet(datasheet);
}
```

New functions used:

- [`Spreadsheet#deleteSheet`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/spreadsheet#deletesheetsheet) (you don't have to activate a sheet to delete it)
- [`Range#getNumColumns`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumcolumns) The width of the `Range`
- [`Range#getNumRows`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#getnumrows) The height of the `Range`

An alternate method, which uses JavaScript arrays to limit the number of Spreadsheet Service methods used, is possible since you appear to only desire the values to be transferred. This takes advantage of chaining, since [`Range#setValues`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#setvaluesvalues) returns a reference to the range that was written into. This assumes that values on the source sheet, "Outcome", don't depend on the workbook. If "Outcome" has formulas that refer to other worksheets in the same workbook, then naturally this won't work, as the values would be in reference to the original workbook, not the destination workbook.

```
  ...
  const dataToCopy = source.getDataRange().getValues();
  dataToCopy.shift(); // remove header row.
  const startRow = target.getLastRow() + 1;
  const numRows = dataToCopy.length;
  const numColumns = dataToCopy[0].length;
  target
    .getRange(startRow, 1, numRows, numColumns)
    .setValues(dataToCopy)
    .offset(0, numColumns, numRows, 1) // offset is from the top-right cell of the range
    .setFormula("some formula");
}
```

- [`Range#offset`](https://developers.google.com/apps-script/reference/spreadsheet/range#offsetrowoffset-columnoffset-numrows-numcolumns)
- [`Array#shift`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/shift)

Comment: You are a wizard. Between the kind folks on Stackoverflow and BenLCollins.com, I'm slowly learning how to use Google Apps Script. Thank you so much for trying to get me to figure it out (I'm a poor student!) and then showing and explaining.